# Trouble with subscribe to Observable in RxJava

Tags: java, kotlin, rx-java, rx-java2

I have an issue where my program are not getting the result from `Observable` in `subscribe()` method.

I'm trying to build simple console app that runs a request to the server and then prints to console the result. And as I see everything works fine but I just can't get the result in `subsribe()`. It seems like the app finishes before the result is returned to the method.

Here is my code running the rquest:

```
coffeeShopApi.getCoffeeShops("")
    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
    .subscribe({
         state.onNext(CoffeeShopViewState.CoffeeShopsLoaded(it))
    }, {
         it.printStackTrace()
         state.onNext(CoffeeShopViewState.Error(it.localizedMessage))
    })
```

After this code is executed the program just finish with exit code 0. And also it runs from main function in the main thread. What could be an issue here?

Comment: I assume you subscribe on a different thread (Schedulers.io()) and the main thread does not wait for the other thread to finish/subscribe. Remove the .subscribeOn  and try it again - than the main thread should be used

Comment: Recommended reading: https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava#simple-background-computation

Comment: @KevinWallis yep, you was right. But shouldn't the program wait until IO finish it's work? Or all of the rx threads run like a daemon threads?

Comment: @Nick it depends - see my answer. There are a lot of different scenarios sometimes it should wait and sometimes it should just do the expensive work in the background.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with your code is that you subscribe on another thread as you current thread (main). Therefore, your main thread finishes before the subscribe for individual items is called.

Here is an example code with a stacktrace:

```
System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + ": start...");

Observable<String> stream = Observable.fromIterable(List.of("a", "b", "c"));
stream.subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
      .subscribe(next -> System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + ": " + next), 
                 error -> error.printStackTrace());

Thread.sleep(1000L);

System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + ": stop...");
```

Stacktrace:

```
main: start...
RxCachedThreadScheduler-1: a
RxCachedThreadScheduler-1: b
RxCachedThreadScheduler-1: c
main: stop...
```

It is shown that the observable is created in the `main` thread. The execution from the subscribe is done in a different thread `RxCachedThreadScheduler-1`.

An example with execution on the same thread:

```
System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + ": start...");

Observable<String> stream = Observable.fromIterable(List.of("a", "b", "c"));
stream.subscribe(next -> System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + ": " + next), 
                 error -> error.printStackTrace());

System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + ": stop...");
```

Stacktrace:

```
main: start...
main: a
main: b
main: c
main: stop...
```

Depending on the use case it can be necessary to wait for the stream execution to finish before the method is further processed e.g. by using the same thread or a `FutureObserver`. In other use cases outsourcing of computational expensive operations into a different thread is a feasible solution.

---

To the question is it a daemon thread? The answer is **yes**. I have attached the test code:

```
String message = String.format("%s-isDaemon?%s: start...", Thread.currentThread().getName(), Thread.currentThread().isDaemon());
System.out.println(message);

Observable<String> stream = Observable.fromIterable(List.of("a", "b", "c"));
stream.subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
      .subscribe(next -> {
                 final String innerMessage = String.format("%s-isDaemon?%s: %s", Thread.currentThread().getName(), Thread.currentThread().isDaemon(), next);
                 System.out.println(innerMessage);
                 },
                 Throwable::printStackTrace);

Thread.sleep(1000L);

message = String.format("%s-isDaemon?%s: stop...", Thread.currentThread().getName(), Thread.currentThread().isDaemon());
System.out.println(message);
```

Output of the stackrace:

```
main-isDaemon?false: start...
RxCachedThreadScheduler-1-isDaemon?true: a
RxCachedThreadScheduler-1-isDaemon?true: b
RxCachedThreadScheduler-1-isDaemon?true: c
main-isDaemon?false: stop...
```

Comment: Yes, I see. If we put the main thread to sleep it will finish all the computation and everything will be fine. But I still don't understand why the process not waiting for the Rx thread to finish. As I know if we run several non-daemon threads in program then the process should wait for the last thread to finish and then finish itself. So all this situation makes me think that Rx uses daemon threads for work. Is it true or not?

Comment: @Nick I have updated my answer - and it is a daemon thread